# Another link will open in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I am currently new in Web development. I am starting to develop my on website. For that I have a button and when I press it a new link will open. I want when I press the button link will open on the same tab and another link will open in new tab. some people told me I have to use JavaScript for solving this problem.I am working on Dreamweaver

Comment: They are right, if you need to do more that open just a link, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Duplicate.

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript**

Comment: @cgatian just beat me to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only specify one 'href' per  tag and hence one link.

```
<a href="http://example.com/link1">Open Link 1 in current tab</a>
```

You can chose to open in a new tag by using the 'target' attribute on the  tag.

```
<a href="http://example.com/link1" target="_blank">Open Link 1 in new tab</a>
```

You can only open two links at the same time (with one in a new tab) using JavaScript.

```
<a href="http://example.com/link1" onclick="
window.open('http://example.com/link1','_blank');
window.open('http://example.com/link2');
return false;">Open Link 1 in new tab and link 2 in this tab</a> 
(If JavaScript is disabled, will open link 1 in this tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need Javascript in order to make it work on an ordinary button. An other option you could choose is to create a div, style it to look like a button and wrap it in a href. This way, you can specify the target: target="_blank".

Check @cgatian's answer for the Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DOM Document Object Model to access window properties and javascript.
just give your button an id and access that id in a javascript function and use the concept of DOM

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using button?
Just use it as link/.
For opening in new tab use

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```

and for opening in same page use

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```